# Does methods takes space after serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, rmi

I have a class like this one:

```
class A{
    int a;
    int b;
    // a lot more properties...

    void methodA(){
       // very long method
    }
    void methodB(){
       // very long method
    }
    // a lot more methods...
}
```

At one point I need to serialize the instance of this class and send it through the net to another node. At the other node only the properties are need, the methods are not. As sending data through the net is expensive, to be light weighted should I make another intermediate class like the following one to strip all the methods and send the serialized instance of this class instead?

```
class A_{
    int a;
    int b;
    // copy all the properties in class A
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Method definitions belong to the class and they don't change for different objects (instances of that class), so it doesn't make sense for them to be included in serialization.

However, the properties of each object can differ, so they are serialized.

So, in conclusion - whether you have zero methods or twenty methods with a hundred lines each, it should make absolutely no difference to serialization.

Comment: How are static properties treated in serialization? Static properties  also don't change for different objects, if the static properties has different value on the remote node, what will happen in deserialization? @Riaan

Comment: @Yulin The simple answer is that they *aren't* treated in serialization.

Answer (score 9):

No.

Serialization does not actually send the methods of the class.  A different number of methods will not change the effects of serialization.

Answer (score 1):

No. Methods do not participate in serialization.

However, if for some reason you have different versions of the same class at each end, they need to:

- agree as to `serialVersionUID`, and
- be serialization-compatible as defined in the Object Versioining chapter of the Object Serialization Specification.

In general this is not a good idea.